# How to perform a fade animation on Activity transition?

Tags: android, animation, android-intent, pending-transition

I  am codifiying a transition effect between my logo activity and my Main activity, but I have the problem that before vanish the activity move to top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <alpha
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" >
    </alpha>

</set>
```

How could I improve this code to get only a vanish effect?

Answer (score 262, accepted):

You could create your own **.xml animation files** to fade in a new `Activity` and fade out the current `Activity`:

fade_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
           android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
           android:duration="500" />
```

fade_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
           android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
           android:fillAfter="true"
           android:duration="500" />
```

Use it in code like that: (Inside your `Activity`)

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, NewlyStartedActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

The above code will fade out the currently active `Activity` and fade in the newly started `Activity` resulting in a smooth transition.

**UPDATE**:
@Dan J pointed out that using the built in Android animations **improves performance**, which I indeed found to be the case after doing some testing. If you prefer working with the built in animations, use:

```
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
```

Notice me referencing `android.R` instead of `R` to access the resource id.

**UPDATE**: It is now common practice to perform transitions using the [Transition class introduced in API level 19](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity).

Comment: Using the built in Android animations seems to result in a smoother transition: `overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fadein, android.R.anim.fadeout);` Viewing those files may also give you hints on how to improve your custom animations (e.g. by making the fade in last longer than the fade out).

Comment: It has an undescore: `overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in,
    android.R.anim.fade_out);` :)

Comment: Do I have to use overridePendingTransition onCreate or in every Intent? Or depends on what I want? Thanks.

Comment: There's a option without "overriding":
`Bundle bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeCustomAnimation(getContext(), android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out).toBundle(); startActivity(intent, bundle);`

Comment: The above transition is executed only if enabled in Developer options, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30422015/2914140.

Comment: What value should I pass for fade_in if I want only the fade out effect without the fade in?

Comment: The built-in Android fade-in animation was very responsive without writing extra code. Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

Just re-posting  [answer by **oleynikd**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475826/how-to-perform-a-fade-animation-on-activity-transition#comment54288215_18475926) because it's simple and neat

```
Bundle bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeCustomAnimation(getContext(),
    android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out).toBundle(); 
startActivity(intent, bundle);
```

To animate while pressing back button,

```
override fun onNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return super.onNavigateUp()
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
```

Comment: Since overridePendingTransition doesn't work in some mobiles and Enes's solution isn't very nice, this answer should be the correct one.

Comment: it works for starting activity but what about coming back(finishing) activity

Comment: Check out updated answer

Answer (score 21):

you can also use this code in your **style.xml** file so you don't need to write anything else in your **activity.java**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/AppTheme.WindowTransition</item>
</style>

<!-- Setting window animation -->
<style name="AppTheme.WindowTransition">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@android:anim/fade_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@android:anim/fade_out</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Not working in SDK 24

Answer (score 19):

you can also add animation in your activity, in onCreate method like below becasue overridePendingTransition is not working with some mobile, or it depends on device settings...

```
View view = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
Animation mLoadAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), android.R.anim.fade_in);
mLoadAnimation.setDuration(2000);
view.startAnimation(mLoadAnimation);
```

Comment: How to handle animation for the previous or parent activity?

Comment: To set the animation for the transition back to the parent activity use this code:
    
    `@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
        
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
    }`