# Let ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor execute tasks on UI thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, executorservice, ui-thread

How can I use a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and schedule a task which is always executed on the UI thread?

Currently, I do the following

```
    mScheduledTask = sBackgroundExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mActivity != null) {
                mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // do UI stuff
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }, 0, 200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

This seems unnecessary and hard to read, but I couldn't find anything in the docs. Is it possible or is this the only way?

Comment: use a Handler and its postDelayed method

Comment: Agreed. See [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Threads/PostDelayed).

Comment: @CommonsWare is it bad to use `Thread.sleep()` instead of handler with postDelayed?

Comment: @Apurva: Please do not use `Thread.sleep()` on the main application thread. `postDelayed()` will be more efficient than anything that uses a background thread (e.g., `Timer`, `ScheduledExecutorService`), as it does not require an additional thread, and you then *still* have to do something to get your work done on the main application thread.